# How would I assign an int into a 2d array?

Tags: c

I have been trying to load a 2d array like this, but i keep getting an error when trying to process this. I'm relatively new to C and I can't seem to figure this out after scrolling forums for a bit.

Mind you, this is a simplified compared to my program but it's the same idea. X would be a counter, y would be some predetermined value that is set earlier in the program, etc.

```
int arr[10][10];
int x = 0;
int y = 12;
arr[x] = y;
```

Any idea how I could resolve this problem?

Comment: The variable `arr` is an array ***of arrays*** of `int` values. That means `arr[x]` is in turn an array which you have to use indexing to access.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `arr` is an array ***of arrays*** of `int` values.

That means `arr[x]` is not an `int`, but an *array* of `int`, which you have to use indexing to access like any other array.

As in:

```
arr[i][j] = y;
```

(where `i` and `j` are valid indexes in respective array)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign an array to an integer.  If you want to just assign one element of it, you could do it like this: `arr[x][0] = y`.  That would set the first element in the 2d array to `y`.  If you want to assign more values, you'd have to iterate through the array.